# Replace words with regular expression And AND Operator

Tags: c#, regex

I want is to replace `BonusInProcent\s=` with `A` and `BonusInProcent\s` with `B`

I tried to find `BonusInProcent\s` and not `BonusInProcent\s=`

```
/(BonusInProcent\s)|(^BonusInProcent\s=)/
```

But this seems wrong! How can I resolve this?

```
EmployeeID == Convert.ToString("50000040")  
Begin 
BonusPerfromanceMultiplier = Convert.ToDecimal("0,5"):
BonusInProcent = Convert.ToDecimal("10")
End; 
EmployeeID == Convert.ToString("50000040") 
Begin 
AlternativeOverAllPerformance =
BonusInProcent * OverAllPerformanceValue * BonusInProcent
End;
```

Comment: Can you try to explain in more detail - or possibly give a few more examples? I understand that English is not your first language, but it is very unclear what you are asking and where you are trying to use the regex.

Comment: This is not C#.... There is no End statement.

Comment: Yeah, looks more like VB, and I don't mean Victoria Bitter.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, oooo that's not language as far as we are concerned. That's the literal string to be Regex'ed!

Comment: @EmpereurAiman, that's not language as far as we are concerned. That's the literal string to be Regex'ed.

Comment: @toddmo, oh. It was wrapped in code tags. Ima edit it k

Comment: Yeah or you can use language none comment above the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need regex of:

```cs
BonusInProcent\s(?!=)
```

to only find BonusInProcent that is NOT followed by equal sign (`=`).

```
myCode = RegEx.Replace(myCode, "BonusInProcent\s(?!=)", "A");
myCode = RegEx.Replace(myCode, "BonusInProcent\s", "B");
```